# Properties of a Product of Commuting Projections

Tags: linear-algebra, projection-matrices, self-adjoint-operators, quantum-information

Let $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$  be two positive-semidefinite projections which commute, and let $\Pi=\Pi_1\Pi_2=\Pi_2\Pi_1$.
Are the following statements correct?

1. $\quad\Pi\:\preceq\:\Pi_1\,$ and $\,\Pi\:\preceq\:\Pi_2$,
   where $A\preceq B$  means $\,B-A\,$ is positive-semidefinite.
2. $\quad I-\Pi\:\preceq\: I-\Pi_1+I-\Pi_2$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Since $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ commute we can show that
$\Pi_1-\Pi$, $\Pi_2-\Pi$, and $\Pi-\Pi_1-\Pi_2+I$
are also projections.

Comment: If $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ are both diagonal matrices, can you solve this?  An attempt is needed here.

Comment: @user8675309 Thanks, I tried but didn't work!

Comment: What have your tried? What definition of "positive semidefinite" are you using? For statement 1, you need to prove that $\Pi_1-\Pi$ must be positive semidefinite. Can you prove that $\Pi_1-\Pi$ is a projection?

Comment: @Luftbahnfahrer I tried to use the definitions and properties of positive semi-definite matrices and also when $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ are diagonal but did not work. I use the formal definition that is, for every $|x>\ne0$ we have $<x|\Pi|x>\geq0$. Yes, I can prove that $\Pi_1-\Pi$ is a projection, because $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ commute.

Comment: Every self-adjoint projection is positive semidefinite. Indeed, suppose $P$ is a self-adjoint projection and let $|x\rangle$ be a vector. Then $\langle x|P|x\rangle=\langle x|P^*P|x\rangle = \langle y|y\rangle\geq0$, where $|y\rangle = P|x\rangle$.

Comment: @Luftbahnfahrer Thanks, that makes sense. Any idea for the second item?

Comment: @Luftbahnfahrer For the second item, it is also possible to prove that $\Pi-\Pi_1-\Pi_2+I$ is a projection. So by using a similar argument, we can show that the second item is also correct. Is that correct?

Comment: I regret that you didn't take the time yet to edit & enhance your post (and you are not a new user). As it stands your post is merely a PSQ.
Pardon, I feel just too impatient ...
1) follows from $\operatorname{range}(\Pi) =\operatorname{range}\Pi_1\cap\operatorname{range}\Pi_2\,$, cf 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3882002/range-of-idempotent-matrices/3882065#3882065
2) is in fact an identity: evaluate $(1-\Pi_1)(1-\Pi_2)$

Comment: @Hanno Thanks, sorry I cannpt follow, how does range$(\Pi)$=range$(\Pi_1)\cap$range$(\Pi_2)$ helps to show that $\Pi_1-\Pi$ is PSD?

Comment: To answer your last question, yes you can prove $I-\Pi_1-\Pi_2+\Pi$ is a projection. And that is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The central assumption "$\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ commute"
implies that $\Pi=\Pi_1\Pi_2=\Pi_2\Pi_1$ is an orthogonal projection as well. It satisfies $\,\operatorname{Im}\Pi=\operatorname{Im}\Pi_1\cap\operatorname{Im}\Pi_2$,
cf [Range of Idempotent matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3882002/316749) .
In particular we have $\Pi_i\Pi=\Pi=\Pi\,\Pi_i\,$.

As in general "something self-adjoint when squared is PSD" one has

1. $\quad 0\:\preceq\:\big(\Pi_i-\Pi\big)^2
    \:=\: \Pi_i -\Pi_i\Pi -\Pi\,\Pi_i +\Pi \:=\: \Pi_i -\Pi$

Since $1-\Pi_1$ and $1-\Pi_2$ are commuting projections their product is alike, thus,

2. $\quad 0\:\preceq\:\big(1-\Pi_1\big)\big(1-\Pi_2\big)
   \:=\: 1 -\Pi_1 -\Pi_2 +\Pi$
   $\qquad\implies 1 -\Pi\:\preceq\:1 -\Pi_1 +1 -\Pi_2$